# jQuery click event not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a `click` function in jQuery and it never seems to execute.  I need another pair of eyes:

The ASP button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Transfer" CssClass="btnSubmit" Enabled="false" />
```

The Javascript/jQuery

```
$(".btnSubmit").click(function () {

    var count = ticks.length;
    var x;

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (ticks[i].Symbol == pair) {
            x = $(".txtAmount").val() * ticks[i].Ask;
            if (x != null || x != 0) {
                $(".txtResult").val() = "=" + x;
            }
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: What  does the rendered markup look like? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Does a disabled button still fire a click event?

Comment: The button is disabled though...

Comment: I remove disable still same result.

Comment: Chris is correct. http://jsfiddle.net/NAUbk/  It is disabled so it will not fire the event.

Comment: When are you binding your event, i.e. `$(function() { // bind event when document ready });` ?

Comment: ok so its not an updatepanel, but this converter does sit within an umbraco built website.

Comment: I removed the asp.net button put in an html input value submit instead. And it seems to work using `onclick=""` instead. Thank you everyone for your help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems as if there is an issue with Umbraco if someone could clarify why this might be I would be greatful.

For now my solution involved doing the following:

Replacing `<asp:Button ID="MyButton" Text="Transfer"></asp:Button>` with `<input type="submit" value="Transfer" onclick="calculate()" />`

Using simple javascript event over the the jquery event. I can get the jquery to work outside of umbraco.

I replaced asp:Button because I do not need a postback on click, and the input field can do the same job for me.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: replace your click function with:

```
$('.btnSubmit').click(function(){
    alert('works');
});
```

If you get an alert, there is something wrong with all that internal code. Can't help you much there since it has a bunch of variable and class names you haven't showed us.

If it doesn't work... maybe issues including jQuery properly?

Anyway, those are just the steps of debugging. Simplify your code to rule out portions/lines and add back in functionality until it breaks. The last thing you added is what is broken.

Comment: yeah the alert doesnt work at all, I have .change working which is odd from jquery sigh no idea whats causing it fireebug and ie javascript debugger doesnt show anything.

Comment: If you can provide a bit more of your code, I may be able to help more. But if the click event isn't even firing (and it's not because the button is disabled per the comments on the question), there's gotta be something else going on.

Comment: instead of .click I am using onclick= instead on an input field.

Answer (score 1):

Is your "txtResult" element a textbox? You cannot assign a value to a textbox like you are here:

```
$(".txtResult").val() = "=" + x;
```

You would need to do this:

```
$(".txtResult")[0].value = "=" + x;
```

Small example: http://jsfiddle.net/wqZmv/

Otherwise I would need to see more of the code if it is a different issue.

Comment: I ended up doing: `$(".txtResult").val('item');` and `var item = "=" + x;` Seems to work for me

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {

var count = ticks.length;
var x;

for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    if (ticks[i].Symbol == pair) {
        x = $(".txtAmount").val() * ticks[i].Ask;
        if (x != null || x != 0) {
            $(".txtResult").val() = "=" + x;
        }
    }
}
```

});

Comment: This will not work because the id of the rendered element is not btnSubmit

Comment: I have tried id's but when working with asp.net and umbraco I can't grab the ClientID because umbraco complains.